# Using dependancies in package.json

Tags: json, npm, gulp

At my internship I had to make a starter using dependancies inside a package.json . And somehow , I could delete the node modules and still run gulp, async and other things you can see in there. Now , I have gulp installed globaly andn i have these dependancies written but when I remove node_modules , terminal says it doesn't recognise gulp. Is there a way to do this ?

[image]

The reason for removing node_modules was that it is a really big folder and as I needed to transfer my projects , they showed my how to remove it .

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var iconfont = require('gulp-iconfont');
var async = require('async');
var consolidate = require('gulp-consolidate');
var sassLint = require('gulp-sass-lint');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});

gulp.task('sass-lint', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.s+(a|c)ss')
        .pipe(sassLint())
        .pipe(sassLint.format())
        .pipe(sassLint.failOnError())
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass'], function (){
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass' , 'sass-lint' ]);
});

gulp.task('build', function (callback) {
    runSequence(['sass'],
        callback
        )
});

gulp.task('iconfont', function(done){
    var iconStream = gulp.src(['app/images/svg/*.svg'])
      .pipe(iconfont({
        fontName: 'icons',
      }));
      async.parallel([
        function handleGlyphs(cb) {
            iconStream.on('glyphs', function(glyphs, options) {
                gulp.src('conf/_iconfont-template.scss')
                  .pipe(consolidate('lodash', {
                    glyphs: glyphs,
                    fontName: 'icons',
                    fontPath: '../fonts/',
                    className: 's'
                  }))
                  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/scss/utilities/'))
                  .on('finish', cb);
              });
            },
            function handleFonts (cb) {
                iconStream
                    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/fonts/'))
                    .on('finish', cb);
            }
          ], done);
});
```

This is my gulpfile.js.

P.S. This also made it so I dont have to install erything everytime . Just do it once , and I can copy the starter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i managed to solve the issue . Gulp was updated to version 4 so I needed to change the code and use

```
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('sass'), function (){
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('sass' , 'sass-lint' )));
});
```